# Program that draws bars from a random array, then selection sorts it in real time with a timer

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, timer, selection-sort

I am trying to write a program that graphically displays a selection sort. It needs to sort bars of various heights, and the bars heights are generated from an array of random integers. The program needs to show the bars swapping as they are being sorted, I am having trouble getting the bars to draw, it needs to look like a bar graph.
Here is my code thus far (not counting my boiler plate):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class SelectionSortPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final int DELAY = 20;
    private int[] RandArray = new int[20];

    Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new BarListener());

    public SelectionSortPanel()
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        //int[] RandArray = new int[20];

    for( int index =0; index<RandArray.length; index++)
    {
        RandArray[index] = gen.nextInt(30)+10;
    }

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        //time.start();
        super.paintComponent(page);


        for(int i = 0; i < RandArray.length; i++)
        {
            page.setColor(Color.red);
            page.fillRect(i * 10, 250, 8, -RandArray[i]);
            timer.start();
        }

    }



    private class BarListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {

            int min;        
            int temp;
            for ( int index = 0; index < RandArray. length- 1; index++)
            {

            min = index;

            for ( int scan = index+ 1;scan < RandArray. length; scan++)


            if (RandArray[index]>RandArray[scan])

            min = scan;

        // Swap the values

            temp = RandArray[min];

            RandArray[min] = RandArray[ index];

            RandArray[index] = temp;

            repaint();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

it will compile but when it is ran nothing happens.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: I attempted to help with the indexing and formatting of your question... I think you are missing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Get that `timer.start()` out of your paintComponent method where it has no business being. You should call this method once, and not inside of a loop as you currently have it (sorry, but that's a little bit strange), and not inside of a method that you have little control over.

In fact nothing should be in the paintComponent method that is unrelated to painting. Also, you should not call `setBackground(...)` or `setPreferredSize()` from in there but rather all of these guys should be called elsewhere such as inside of your class's constructor. The `paintComponent` method should also be `protected`, not `public`, and should have an `@Override` annotation above it.

---

**Edit**
Also, you might want to get rid of one of the for loops since the Timer will in effect replace it. You need to consider the actionPerformed method section of your Timer's ActionListener as if it were the inside of a for loop. But I will need to look at your code further on this issue.

---

**Edit 2**
Also, at your current stage of programming, I strongly urge you to make sure that **all** of your code blocks, including *if* blocks, *while* loops, etc, should be enclosed in curly braces. You have one if block that may not be working as you expect it because you are missing these braces. Also you need to be extremely careful and accurate with your code indentation, and for the same reason -- good proper code indentation will help you see at a glance what block of code belongs where, and helps you in your debugging and code understanding efforts.

---

**Edit 3**
Your `Graphics#fillRect(...)` height parameter should not be negative. Also avoid magic numbers. Doing so will help you improve your code much more easily and logically -- such as those magic numbers in your paintComponent drawRect method.

---

**Edit 4**

- I was wrong about the for loop business -- keep your for loops where they are.
- I'd make my timer delay a bit slower, say 500 msec, not 20 msec.
- You will want to stop your Timer run when everything is sorted -- so test for that.

---

**Edit 5**
For example, my paintComponent and getPreferredSize (instead of setPreferredSize) method overrides would look something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  int prefW = BAR_GAP + RAND_ARRAY_LENGTH * (BAR_GAP + BAR_WIDTH);
  int prefH = MAX_BAR * SCALE + 2 * BAR_GAP;
  return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
  super.paintComponent(page);
  for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
     page.setColor(Color.red);
     int x = BAR_GAP + i * (BAR_WIDTH + BAR_GAP);
     int height = SCALE * randArray[i];
     int y = MAX_BAR * SCALE - height;
     page.fillRect(x, y, BAR_WIDTH, height);
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou, but it still wont display bars, i ran a print test at the bottom and it is coming up with 0s for my array values so my problem lies in the array not keeping the values?

Comment: @user3530192: time to do some debugging, using a debugger or println statemetns. Also see edit to answer. You need to get rid of the for loop inside of the ActionListener.

Comment: anywhere else i put the loop it does not recognize page?

Comment: when you run the code how it is what is happening for you?

Comment: I have to go to work, Ill revisit this after, thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You need a main method to run it... slap that in and it sorts some bars.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    SelectionSortPanel panel = new SelectionSortPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: i have this in when i set up my frame on my boiler plate, but i put this in now, It still just comes up with a barless frame.

Comment: is it doing the sorting too? how are you getting that i get a blank screen?

Comment: yeah it sorts it (really fast, so you hardly see it).  I'm not really sure what's wrong with yours.  Open task manager and see if a new Java process is made when you run it?

Comment: what do you mean by blank screen?  is there a black rectangle? or is there no black background at all?  Does a new window appear at all?

Comment: it sets up the frame, but there are no rectangles.

Comment: compare your frame setup to the one I posted... i presume you're missing a step

Comment: `code`import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sort
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Displays the main frame of the program.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Selection Sort");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane().add(new SelectionSortPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}`code`

Comment: uhh i got the format wrong, but i used your frame and it still did not work

Comment: This line:  page.fillRect(i * 10, 250, 8, -RandArray[i]);  is the problem.  It doesn't like negative height.  fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height), so try this instead:  page.fillRect(i * 10, 250 - RandArray[i], 8, RandArray[i]);